# Why should a person sprinkle water on himself, if he sneezes at a door entrance (Gadapa)?

Tags: belief, culture, superstitions

Why should a person sprinkle water on himself, if he sneezes at a door entrance (Gadapa)?

Comment: Also We must take a sip of water if we sneeze while eating. Don't know about this one.

Comment: Read: Apastamba Prasna 2, Patala 2, Khanda 3

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda it's difficult to prove what you said is incorrect, but please feel free to quote any sources, if any

Comment: @asgs In any logical proof, you can only prove a positive, not a negative. Scripture does not list what superstitions are not true.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda understand that, but was looking for any sources, not Scriptures, really

Comment: @asgs proofs lie in the assertion, not in the negation.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, then prove your assertion that it is superstition. If you cannot, then just say you don't know, or that you're guessing that it is superstition.

Comment: @ram Again, proof lies in the assertion. You assert that one should sprinkle. What is your assertion based on? I neither assert or deny, but until you can prove your assertion, its superstition.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - superstition - "a widely held but unjustified belief in supernatural causation". you just asserted that it is superstition. that means you are saying their belief is unjustified i.e. they do not know the reason behind it. do you know whether they know the reason or not ? if somebody asked me why they sprinkle water, I would say "i do not know, probably it is family/elders tradition". I would not say "it is superstition", unless I know for sure how the tradition originated.

Comment: @ram It is precisely because you do not know how it originated that it is superstition. We all have superstitions. Once a man was invited to have dinner with Sir Issac Newton. As they approached Sir Issac's house, the man noticed a horseshoe above the entrance (an old English superstition to bring good luck). He pointed out the horseshoe to Sir Issac and remarked to Sir Issac - " I thought you were not a superstitious person?" To which Sir Issac replied "I am not. But I understand that it works even if you don't believe in it."

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, the question is whether or not YOU (i.e. Vishwananda) know how it originated. When you call something as superstition, you are asserting that nobody knows how it originated. If someone asks "why do some people touch their nose & ears after yawning", and if you do not know why and if you say it is superstition, you would be wrong, because I (i.e. ram) know the shastric reason behind it. So, the scientific and wise thing would be to say "I do not know why people sprinkle water on themselves, maybe someone else knows the reason, or maybe it is unjustified superstition".

Comment: Any act of sprinkling water with mantras is to clean oneself. Bathing all the time is not possible. Shankaracharya Chandrasekhara Saraswathi (periyavaal), would bathe even after normal nature calls.. since that is not feasible for normal folks, there are 'mini' bathings like prokshanam, achamanam, for yawning/sneezing/farting. If even that is not possible, there is a even shorter versions of that. Meditating on Sri Hari is the shortest/easiest form of bathing. Yudhistira says in Yaksha Prashan - Snanam Mano Mala Tyagaha. (Bathing means shedding bad thoughts from mind)

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge.. We have to sprinkle that water on door entrance instead of ourselves.

The 'maybe' reason behind that -
According to Hindus, there is laxmi at door entrance, and as sneezing consist of germs, we sprinkle waters to fool. ( like.. Its just a water sprinkle n not sneeze)

Just liks after taking prashad, if we want to go the toilet, we advised to have a sip water just to fool.. As we are peeing that water n not prashad. :)

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! Cite Sources for your answer.Also try to mentain quality standards while providing examples in answer.

Answer (score 1):

My grandfather explained why they were told to sprinkle water in entrance. Everything told in age old were scientific but unfortunately lot are outdated practices followed blindly. 
Below is the actual reason :
In olden days majority were huts & small homes built with wet mud compacted entrance (read entrance flooring)  . So whenever someone sneezes whole passing the entrance.. the vibrations will cause the mud to loose & crack with time.. Hence to maintain its compacted state they were asked to sprinkle water & maintain the moist state.

This is also the reason why they sprinkle water before putting kolam. Kolam traditionally was put on the mud compacted entrance. So the practice of sprinkling water every morning was to ensure the entrance flooring is well compacted maintained everyday as dry mud may loosen up with time

Comment: Kolam is put so that small beings like ants and insects are fed, and also so they don't enter the home searching for sugar or food and get trampled.